# MySQL Update Colum Based On Other Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this table :

```
table_a
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
| 10 | ERROR  |
+----+--------+
```

and I also have this table :

```
table_b
+------------+----------------+
| trading_id | trading_status |
+------------+----------------+
|         10 | CLOSED         |
+------------+----------------+
```

how to `UPDATE` `table_a.status` based on `table_b.trading_status` so that the result will be like this :

```
table_a
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
| 10 | CLOSED |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE table_a
JOIN   table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
SET    table_a.status = table_b.trading_status
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET status = COALESCE((SELECT trading_status
                       FROM table_b 
                       WHERE trading_id = table_a.id), table_a.status)
```

The above query assumes there is at most one record in `table_b` matching each record of `table_a`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0aab1/1)